# JSTL and hashmap not working

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

In a servlet I have:

```
HashMap eventsByDayNo = new HashMap();
eventsByDayNo.put (new Integer(12), "day 12 info");
eventsByDayNo.put (new Integer(11), "day 11 info");
eventsByDayNo.put (new Integer(15), "day 15 info");
eventsByDayNo.put (new Integer(16), "day 16 info");

request.setAttribute("eventsByDayNo", eventsByDayNo);
request.setAttribute("daysInMonth", new Integer(31));
```

And in a jsp I have:

```
<c:forEach var="dn" begin="1" end="${daysInMonth}" step="1" varStatus="status">
  Day Number=<c:out value="${dn}" /> Value=<c:out value="${eventsByDayNo[dn]}" /><br>
</c:forEach>
```

The above JSTL works fine, but if I try to offset the day number `<c:out value="${eventsByDayNo[dn+3]}" />`
none of the hashmap entries are not printed.  Any answers as to why not?

The above is just a proof of concept for my real application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `dn+3` has type `java.lang.Double`, not `java.lang.Integer` (which you may expect).

```
<ul>
<c:forEach var="dn" begin="1" end="${daysInMonth}" step="1">
  <li>
    <c:set var="dnplus3" value="${dn+3}" />
    dn=<c:out value="${dn}" />
    dnplus3=<c:out value="${dnplus3}" />
    class=<c:out value="${dnplus3.class.name}" />
  </li>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are right, I'm expecting an Integer but it is a long dn=1 dnplus3=4 class=java.lang.Long.

Comment: For the reference, the *Expression Language Specification Version 2.2* defines in section 1.7.1 the operator `+`, which in this case results in a `Long` value.

Comment: Just thinking that this is an example of strong typing fighting back, instead of preventing errors as it was supposed to do, is not doing what the user expects.

Answer (score 3):

Numbers (at least, whole numbers) in EL are implicitly treated as `Long`. So replace your `Map<Integer, String>` by a `Map<Long, String>` and it will work.